# ComboBox draw image on selected item

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, combobox, drawimage

I try to draw an image from a image list in a ComboBox when the item is selected.

I am able to draw the image, but when the `onSelctedIndexChanged` event finish, I lost my image.

My ComboBox already have the `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`.

I have a `ListImage` control named ImageList with 10 pictures.

For my short example I just need to draw in my ComboBox the image at position 1 of my ImageList, it's the reason why I get  `this.ImageList.Draw(g, 0, 0, **1**);`

```
protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
    
    if (this.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
      var g = this.CreateGraphics();
      this.ImageList.Draw(g, 0, 0, 1);   
    }
}
```

Probably I am not subscribing to the right event. Any suggestion?

See the picture below with a breakpoint in `SelectedIndexChanged` after the image is drawn. It works, but I lose my image after the event.

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate when people give some negative score without explanation !!!

Comment: If you are going to draw stuff, you usually want an OwnerDraw mode control, which means you use the DrawItem method,  `CreateGraphics` though is almost never the right way and likely the reason for the image being "lost"...beyond that, this is a bit vague

Comment: My DrawMode is already set to OwnerDrawFixed

Comment: `var g = this.CreateGraphics();` Never use `CreateGraphics`! Use the Graphics object of the `DrawXX` or `PaintXX` event parameters! You may want to trigger the `Paint/DrawItem` event by `Invalidate()`'ing the control in the SelChanged event. So move the code there and call `this.Invalidate();` Note that it often also has useful info to help with the drawing.. If the `ImageList.Draw` is a function of yours you can pass in the Graphics object, provided a) is is valid (ie comes from the e.paramter) and b) it is not cached.

Comment: @TaW i understand what you said, but the DrawItem for a combobox are use to draw the Items of the control. When you click on the arrow to see the elements inside the controls. When you select an item, insted if you was draw someting inside the "drop down menu" you lost the "background" it's the reason why I write code inside the SelectedItems. But probably i did not have the right approach !?

Comment: The only way to create a __persistent__ drawing is to use the right Graphics object at the right time. Ownerdrawing often involves drawing the Backgroud as well.

Comment: The are numerous answers here showing how to draw things in the CBO drop down.  Look a few up to see how it is done.  Drawing has to happen in the DrawItem event for it to persist, period

Comment: Also note, as mentioned in Jimi's answer: The text posrtion will only be owner-draw if the style if ddList,. This is because otherwise this portion is a TextBox behind the scenes and good old TextBox doesn't support owner-drawing. You could try by subclassing the whole combobox, but it'll not work well, if at all..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your ComboBox [DrawMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx) to `OwnerDrawVariable`.
Use the [DrawItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx) event to draw the images from your source (an ImageList, in this case) inside the ComboBox item Bounds.

If the ComboBox [DropDownStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) is set to `DropDownList`, the image will be shown in the selection box; if it's set to `DropDown`, only the text will be drawn.

Here, the Focus rectangle is only drawn when the mouse point hovers the ListControl's items, while it's not used when an item is selected, which is determined by:
**`(e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Focus) && !e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit))`**.

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index < 0) return;
    var cbo = sender as ComboBox;
    Color foreColor = e.ForeColor;

    if (e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected) && !(e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit))) {
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.DrawFocusRectangle(); // <= could be removed for a cleaner rendering
    }
    else {
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(cbo.BackColor)) {
            var rect = e.Bounds;
            rect.Inflate(1, 1);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
        }
        foreColor = cbo.ForeColor;
    }
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, cbo.GetItemText(cbo.Items[e.Index]), e.Font,
        new Point(e.Bounds.Height + 10, e.Bounds.Y), foreColor);

    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[e.Index],
                         new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Location,
                         new Size(e.Bounds.Height - 2, e.Bounds.Height - 2)));
}
```

The *Magic Numbers* here (`10, -2`) are just offsets:
`e.Bounds.Height + 10 =>` 10 pixels to the right of the image.
`e.Bounds.Height -2 =>`   2 pixels less than the `item.Bounds.Height`.

[image: ComboBox Ownerdraw with Images]

Comment: You are creating brushes that need to be disposed.  Alternatively, you can just use the built-in brushes: Brushes.White, Brushes.Black, etc.

Comment: @ LarsTech  ...but using stock brushes would defeat the purpose of having `.ForeColor`/`BackColor` properties, so back to disposing the new(ed) brushes.