# Winforms Combobox height change manually input value

Tags: winforms, combobox

When I add Combobox control to a Winforms interface, its height is changed from the the value I set to another value in my case 22 however I set it to 25. If I try to change it using HawkEye, it changes it back to 22. How can I change the size of a such a control to the wanted value? I already tried the autosize solution :

> myCtrl.AutoSize = false;

Comment: If you set its [DrawMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx) to `OwnerDrawVariable` or `OwnerDrawFixed`, you can set its `ItemHeight` to whatever value you see fit. Of course, you'll have to draw its content (subscribing its `DrawItem` and `MeasureItem` events). A sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102456/combobox-draw-image-on-selected?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

ComboBoxes pick their height automatically from the Font that they contain. If you want your combobox to be smaller, then set the point size of your font smaller.

E.G.

If you're using the standard MS Sans Serif at 8.75pt (9 on the font edit screen) then the combobox will be 25 pixels tall.

A font size of 8.25pt (8 on the font edit screen) will give you your 22 pixel height.