# How to display selected item in ComboBox when OwnerDrawn?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm cusom drawing a combobox and I have overriden `OnPaint` and `OnDrawItem`. So far everything works fine.

However, after I select an item from the list and the list closes, the selected item is not displayed in the text portion of the combobox.

Which messages do I need to handle to draw the item there?

I added the following when handling WM_PAINT:

```
if (SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    g.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

Should I do my drawing in `WndProc` or `OnPaint`?

**UPDATE:**

This is the code for the `WndProc` and `OnDrawItem` events. In `WndProc` I draw the control's surace (text portion, button, border). In `DrawItem` I draw the item.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
        {
            var dc = GetWindowDC(this.Handle);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromHdc(dc))
            {
                var theme = ThemeManager.Theme;
                if (theme == null)
                {
                    var outer = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
                    var inner = new Rectangle(1, 1, this.Width - 2, this.Height - 2);

                    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, outer, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
                    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, inner, this.BackColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Focused ? theme.ComboBoxFocusBackColor : theme.ComboBoxBackColor))
                    {
                        if (SelectedIndex == -1)
                        {
                            g.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
                        }

                        int arrowWidth = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
                        var center = new Point(this.Width - arrowWidth / 2, this.Height / 2);

                        //Down
                        Point[] arrow = new[] {
                            new Point(center.X - 4, center.Y - 2),
                            new Point(center.X + 4, center.Y - 2),
                            new Point(center.X, center.Y + 4)
                        };

                        g.FillPolygon(theme.GetTextBrush(), arrow);
                    }

                    var borderColor = MouseState == MouseState.Hover
                        ? theme.BorderOverColor
                        : Focused
                            ? theme.BorderFocusColor
                            : Enabled
                                ? theme.BorderColor
                                : theme.BorderDisabledColor;

                    var outer = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
                    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, outer, borderColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
                }
            }

            ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, dc);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e);

        if (e.Index == -1)
            return;

        var theme = ThemeManager.Theme;
        if (theme == null)
            return;

        var selected = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            || ((e.State & DrawItemState.Focus) == DrawItemState.Focus)
            || ((e.State & DrawItemState.HotLight) == DrawItemState.HotLight);

        using (var backBrush = new SolidBrush(selected ? theme.ComboBoxSelectionBackColor : theme.ComboBoxBackColor))
        using (var foreBrush = new SolidBrush(selected ? theme.ComboBoxSelectionForeColor : theme.TextColor))
        {
            var g = e.Graphics;

            g.FillRectangle(backBrush, e.Bounds);

            var item = Convert.ToString(FilterItemOnProperty(Items[e.Index]));
            g.DrawString(item, Font, foreBrush, e.Bounds);
        }

        if (theme != null)
        {
            DrawDropDownBorder(e, theme);
        }
    }
```

However, there are some inconsistencies, especially after selecting an item, because the drawing done in `WndProc` is overridden.

Comment: None. If the DropDownStyle is `DropDown`, the Item's text is shown, if it's `DropDownList`, the Item's *content* (Graphics and Text, i.e., what you have drawn). See here: [Combobox draw image on selected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103139/7444103) (the example there is incomplete - `DrawFocusRectangle()` is not actually implemented - but it shows the result). The `ComboBox.Items` list needs to contain *something* that `[ComboBox].GetItemText()` can translate to a string.

Comment: @Jimi I'm also drawing the text portion using `FillRectangle`. The selected item is being drawn correctly, however it's quickly replaced by the drawing of the text portion background. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: `FillRectangle`? How do you draw Text with that method? Use `Graphics.DrawString` or `TextRenderer.DrawText`. But you have render the content of `Item[e.Index]`.

Comment: @Jimi I first draw the background and border on handling WM_PAINT. Then I draw the item in OnDrawItem.

Comment: Can you post the code you have in the DrawItem method? Maybe also what you're doing (related to the Item's background) when you receive a `WM_PAINT` (this is not usually required, in relation to the Item's content, you can perform all the drawing in the DrawItem method). `WM_PAINT` is related to the Control's *surface*.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it appears you're redrawing just the background and only if `SelectedIndex == -1`. In `DrawItem`, you could have `if (theme == null) { base.OnDrawItem(e); return; }`. As of now, you painting each Item twice. The procedure is more complex than this, if you want to handle the design in `WM_PAINT`. The different `DropDownStyle`s  are not handled here, for example.

Comment: When in `DropDownList` mode, the ComboBox content is rendered by the DrawItem method. See also: [ComboBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.comboboxrenderer.drawtextbox)

Comment: @Jimi I'm using only `DropDownList`. I don't understand where in the code I'm painting twice. `WndProc` is for the control itself (backcolor, border) and `OnDrawItem` for the items.