# How to create a DrawItemEventHandler and call a delegate in Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, event-handling, delegates

I'm not sure why this won't work, which type is create delegate looking for here?

For a little more information, I'm trying to call "add_DrawItem" upon initialization of the form so it can give an empty entry box with an image in it. If there is another way to do this, I'm open to that, as long as my combobox has an editable text entry area with an image.

```
$comboBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox;
$comboBox.DrawMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode]::OwnerDrawFixed;
$comboBox.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDown;
$delegateTest = [System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler]::CreateDelegate([System.MulticastDelegate], $comboBox, "add_DrawItem")
```

> Exception calling "CreateDelegate" with "3" argument(s): "Type must
> derive from Delegate.

I've also tried and failed with

```
$methodInfo = $comboBox.GetType().GetMethod("add_DrawItem");
$type = [System.Action[System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler]];
$comboBoxDrawItemEventHandlerT = [System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler]::CreateDelegate($type, $methodInfo);
```

> Exception calling "CreateDelegate" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot bind
> to the target method because its signature or security transparency is
> not compatible with that of the  delegate type."
>
> .

***Working example code below***

```
cls;

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(450, 180)   
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.Topmost = $true;

$image1 = "c:\xxx.png";
$image2 = "c:\xxx.png";
$image3 = "c:\xxx.png";
$image4 = "c:\xxx.png";
$image5 = "c:\xxx.png"
$imageDefault = "c:\xxx.png";

$imgLbl = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label;
$imgLbl.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($imageDefault);
$imgLbl.AutoSize = $false;
$imgLbl.Size = $imgLbl.Image.Size;
$imgLbl.ImageAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleLeft;
$imgLbl.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleLeft;
$imgLbl.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Transparent;
$imgLbl.Tag = "Default";

$tbxComboboxDD = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox;
$tbxComboboxDD.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom;
$tbxComboboxDD.Anchor += [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left;
$tbxComboboxDD.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
$sizeWidth = (308);
$sizeHeight = (30);
$tbxComboboxDD.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($sizeWidth, $sizeHeight);
$tbxComboboxDD.TextAlign = [System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment]::Left;
$tbxComboboxDD.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft San Serif",11,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)

$comboboxDD = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$comboboxDD.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
$comboboxDD.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(390, 25)  
$comboboxDD.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList;
$comboboxDD.FlatStyle = "Flat"
$comboboxDD.BackColor = 'White'
$comboboxDD.Font = "Arial,11pt,style=Bold"
$comboboxDD.DrawMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode]::OwnerDrawFixed;
$comboboxDD.Controls.Add($imgLbl);
$comboboxDD.Controls.Add($tbxComboboxDD);
$comboboxDD.SendToBack();
$comboboxDD.Invalidate();
$comboboxDD.DisplayMember = "AccountName";
$comboboxDD.Name = "cbxUserName2";

$imgLbl.Parent = $comboboxDD;
$imgLbl.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(1, 1);
$imgLbl.Show();

$tbxComboboxDD.Parent = $comboboxDD;
$tbxComboboxDD.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(62, -5);
$tbxComboboxDD.BorderStyle = [Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::None;

$tbxComboboxDD.Visible = $true;
$tbxComboboxDD.Show();

$tbxComboboxDD.add_KeyPress({
    param(
    [System.Object] $sender, 
    [System.EventArgs] $e
    )
    $global:tbxComboboxDDAddKeyPressSender = $sender;
    $global:tbxComboboxDDAddKeyPressEventArgs = $e;
    
    Write-Host "Entering tbxComboboxDD.add_KeyPress";
    if ($imgLbl.Tag -eq "Type2")
    {
        $tbxComboboxDD.Text = "";
        $imgLbl.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($imageDefault);
        $imgLbl.Tag = "Default";
        $tbxComboboxDDAddKeyPressEventArgs.Handled = $true;
    }
    Write-Host $imgLbl.Tag;
});

$comboboxDD.add_SelectionChangeCommitted({
    param(
    [System.Object] $sender, 
    [System.EventArgs] $e
    )
    
    $global:comboBoxDDAddSelectionChangeCommittedSender = $sender;
    $global:comboBoxDDAddSelectionChangeCommittedEventArgs = $e;
    
    
    foreach ($item in $comboboxDDAddSelectionChangeCommittedSender.Items)
    {
        if ($item.AccountName -eq $comboboxDDAddSelectionChangeCommittedSender.Text)
        {
            $global:comboboxDDAddSelectionChangeCommittedSelectedObject = $item;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    $tbxComboboxDD.Text = $comboboxDDAddSelectionChangeCommittedSender.Text;
    $imgLbl.Tag = $comboboxDDAddSelectionChangeCommittedSelectedObject.AccountType;
    $imgLbl.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($correspondingSelectionImagePath);
    Write-Host $imgLbl.Tag;
    Write-Host "Entering comboboxDD.add_SelectionChangeCommitted";
});

$comboboxDD.Add_DrawItem({
    
 param(
    [System.Object] $sender, 
    [System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs] $e
    )
    
    Write-Host "Entering comboboxDD.Add_DrawItem";
    $global:comboboxDDAddDrawItemSender = $sender;
    $global:comboboxDDDrawItemEventArgs = $e;
    $global:item = $sender.Items[$e.Index];
    
    switch ($item.AccountType.Trim())
    {
        "Type1"  { if ($currentComboboxItem.AccountStatus.Trim() -eq "Valid") { $comboBoxAccountImage = $image1; }
                    elseif ($currentComboboxItem.AccountStatus.Trim() -eq "Invalid") { $comboBoxAccountImage = $image1; }
                    break;}
                    
        "Type2"  { if ($currentComboboxItem.AccountStatus.Trim() -eq "Valid") { $comboBoxAccountImage = $image2; }
                    elseif ($currentComboboxItem.AccountStatus.Trim() -eq "Invalid") { $comboBoxAccountImage = $image2; }
                    break;}
                    
        "Type3"  { if ($currentComboboxItem.AccountStatus -eq "Valid") { $comboBoxAccountImage = $image3; }
                    elseif ($currentComboboxItem.AccountStatus -eq "Invalid") { $comboBoxAccountImage = $image3; }
                    break;}
        
        "Type4"  { if ($currentComboboxItem.AccountStatus.Trim() -eq "Valid") { $comboBoxAccountImage = $image4; }
                    elseif ($currentComboboxItem.AccountStatus.Trim() -eq "Invalid") { $comboBoxAccountImage = $image4; }
                    break;}
                    
        "Type5"  { if ($currentComboboxItem.AccountStatus.Trim() -eq "Valid") { $comboBoxAccountImage = $image5; }
                    elseif ($currentComboboxItem.AccountStatus.Trim() -eq "Invalid") { $comboBoxAccountImage = $image5; }
                    break;}

        
        "default"  { $comboBoxAccountImage = $imageDefault; break; }                        
        
    }
    
    [Byte[]]$comboBoxAccountImageByteArr = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($comboBoxAccountImage);
    $memoryStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream(, $comboBoxAccountImageByteArr);
    $dropDownImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromStream($memoryStream);
    $bitmapGuid = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Bmp;        
    $imageFormat = New-Object System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat $bitmapGuid.Guid
    $bitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($dropDownImage, 62, 18);
    $saveMemoryStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream;
    $bitmap.Save($saveMemoryStream, $imageFormat.Guid); 
    $image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromStream($saveMemoryStream);
    $image.Tag = $comboBoxAccountImage;
    $global:correspondingSelectionImagePath = $comboBoxAccountImage;
    $global:correspondingSelectionImage = $image;
    
    $backgroundColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White;
    $backgroundColorBrush = New-Object System.Drawing.SolidBrush($backgroundColor);
    $textColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Black;
    $textColorBrush = New-Object System.Drawing.SolidBrush($textColor);

    $font = $e.Font
    $e.Graphics.FillRectangle($backgroundColorBrush, $e.Bounds);    
    $e.Graphics.DrawImage($image, (new-object System.Drawing.PointF($e.Bounds.X, $e.Bounds.Y)));    
    $e.Graphics.DrawString($item.AccountName, $font, $textColorBrush, (new-object System.Drawing.PointF(($image.Width + 5), $e.Bounds.Y)));
    
    
        
});



$itemsList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;

$accountName = "Sample1";
$accountType = "Type1";
$accountStatus = "Valid";
$item = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountName" -Value $accountName -TypeName String;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountType" -Value $accountType -TypeName String;           
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountStatus" -Value $accountStatus -TypeName String;
$itemsList.Add($item) | Out-Null;

$accountName = "Sample2";
$accountType = "Type1";
$accountStatus = "Invalid";
$item = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountName" -Value $accountName -TypeName String;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountType" -Value $accountType -TypeName String;           
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountStatus" -Value $accountStatus -TypeName String;
$itemsList.Add($item) | Out-Null;

$accountName = "Sample3";
$accountType = "Type2";
$accountStatus = "Valid";
$item = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountName" -Value $accountName -TypeName String;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountType" -Value $accountType -TypeName String;           
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountStatus" -Value $accountStatus -TypeName String;
$itemsList.Add($item) | Out-Null;

$accountName = "Sample4";
$accountType = "Type2";
$accountStatus = "Invalid";
$item = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountName" -Value $accountName -TypeName String;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountType" -Value $accountType -TypeName String;           
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountStatus" -Value $accountStatus -TypeName String;
$itemsList.Add($item) | Out-Null;


$accountName = "Sample5";
$accountType = "Type3";
$accountStatus = "Valid";
$item = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountName" -Value $accountName -TypeName String;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountType" -Value $accountType -TypeName String;           
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountStatus" -Value $accountStatus -TypeName String;
$itemsList.Add($item) | Out-Null;

$accountName = "Sample6";
$accountType = "Type3";
$accountStatus = "Invalid";
$item = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountName" -Value $accountName -TypeName String;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountType" -Value $accountType -TypeName String;           
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountStatus" -Value $accountStatus -TypeName String;
$itemsList.Add($item) | Out-Null;

$accountName = "Sample7";
$accountType = "Type4";
$accountStatus = "Valid";
$item = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountName" -Value $accountName -TypeName String;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountType" -Value $accountType -TypeName String;           
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountStatus" -Value $accountStatus -TypeName String;
$itemsList.Add($item) | Out-Null;

$accountName = "Sample8";
$accountType = "Type4";
$accountStatus = "Invalid";
$item = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountName" -Value $accountName -TypeName String;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountType" -Value $accountType -TypeName String;           
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountStatus" -Value $accountStatus -TypeName String;
$itemsList.Add($item) | Out-Null;

$accountName = "Sample9";
$accountType = "Type5";
$accountStatus = "Valid";
$item = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountName" -Value $accountName -TypeName String;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountType" -Value $accountType -TypeName String;           
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountStatus" -Value $accountStatus -TypeName String;
$itemsList.Add($item) | Out-Null;

$accountName = "Sample10";
$accountType = "Type5";
$accountStatus = "Invalid";
$item = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountName" -Value $accountName -TypeName String;
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountType" -Value $accountType -TypeName String;           
$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "AccountStatus" -Value $accountStatus -TypeName String;
$itemsList.Add($item) | Out-Null;

foreach ($item in $itemsList)
{
    $comboboxDD.items.Add($item) | Out-Null;
}


$form.Controls.Add($comboboxDD);
[void]$form.showdialog();
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to *call DrawItem*? That event is raised as soon as an Item needs to be drawn (i.e., as soon as the Form is shown). Just subscribe to the event. -- No graphic is drawn in the TextBox of a ComboBox, i.e., when `DropDownStyle` is `DropDown`. Set it to `DropDownList`

Comment: @Jimi , the issue with dropdownlist is that the user cannot type into it, it is not editable. I want to call drawitem or emulate it as I am drawing images next to the items enumerated in the combobox dropdown.

Comment: When the `DropDownStyle` of a ComboBox is set to `DropDown`, you can draw images in the ListControl but not in the Edit Control (the native TextBox) that shows editable text. -- The DrawItem method is called each time an Item needs to be drawn, you don't have to call it (it handles an event); I don't know what *emulate it* could mean, in your view. -- Do you need the `DropDown` style because you have enabled the AutoComplete feature of that ComboBox? Otherwise, it's pretty much useless.

Comment: See code and notes here: [ComboBox draw image on selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103139/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi I have added an image to show the functionality I am trying to emulate. If you use get-credential in a Powershell console, you'll see how the dropdownlist has an image and a blank textbox, it has dropdown items with images and the image loads by default. This is what I am trying to emulate, specifically the event that is called with `combobox.add_drawitem()` , however I am open to doing this a better way if there is another option.

Comment: `combobox.add_drawitem()` doesn't *call an event*, it registers an event and you specify a delegate, as in `$comboBox.Add_DrawItem({DrawItem})`. Then you write your function delegate, e.g., `Function DrawItem() { $_.DrawBackground( [System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer]::DrawText($_.Graphics, $this.Items[$_.Index], $_.Font, $_.Bounds, $_.ForeColor) }` (minimal, drawing default stuff) -- The ComboBox you're referring to is not a Windows Forms ComboBox, that's a Win32 Custom ComboBox UserControl, where the bounds of the Edit Control have been redefined, to leave some space for an Image.

Comment: You *could* do something similar in WinForms (or exactly the same, for that matter), but this implies that you need to create a Custom Control and PInvoke the heck out of it. Or fake it, redesigning the left border of the ComboBox, draw an extended border that leaves some space to draw the Image associated to an ImageList, corresponding to the index of the current Item in the ComboBox.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the nudging in the right direction. I created a combobox and added child controls of a label for the image and textbox and that allows me the functionality I wanted and to be able to manipulate text alignment. I've put the code in the question, they'll need to be 6 small thumbnails (about 60x20 pixels) in a folder and referenced at the top for the images, to see how it works. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Jimi if you want to submit an answer, I will mark it as answered and give you credit.